# Get source image and show in Image WPF

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I writing a WPF application. At the moment I need some C# code to take the image source from an html page at this node:

```
<img width="260" height="146" alt="Big Bang Theory.png" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/thumb/9/98/Big_Bang_Theory.png/260px-Big_Bang_Theory.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/thumb/9/98/Big_Bang_Theory.png/390px-Big_Bang_Theory.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/thumb/9/98/Big_Bang_Theory.png/520px-Big_Bang_Theory.png 2x" data-file-height="351" data-file-width="623">
```

To take the image source I used this:

```
string img = docSerie.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='sinottico']").
            SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='image']").FirstChild.GetAttributeValue("src", null);
```

But I don't understand how to use this source. I tried:

```
logo.Source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(img) as ImageSource;
```

or simply

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(img, UriKind.Absolute);
bitmap.EndInit();
logo.Source;
```

logo is the image tool name of my WPF, But doesn't work. In the second block I received an error at "bitmap.EndInit();" is unable to find a path.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing image in WPF using the URL link from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435829/showing-image-in-wpf-using-the-url-link-from-database)

Comment: Please show us the `img` string. If it's a valid URL, `new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(img) as ImageSource` should work, or just `new BitmapImage(new (Uri(img))`

Comment: Ver Nick is right, my question is very similar. I tried that suggestion but doesn't work. So I replied here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435829/showing-image-in-wpf-using-the-url-link-from-database/54151183#54151183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the image tool name of your WPF as

```
logo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(img));
```

Answer (score 0):

Both suggestion didn't work (the other post and the Bhuvanesh Jay's one) untill I added "html:\" to the source. Isn't weird? If I copy and past the source on internet it works fine but C# need the html:\ otherwise it can't find the link.

By the way, the problem was solved. Thanks a lot.