# Any way to load an online image into a richtextbox

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to set an image into a richtextbox.
Can this be done and if so how?

Will I have to use an online textbox and load it into my form using the webbrowser, such as with monaco?

Using the properties menu, I do not see anything about images in the richtextbox, only backcolor, so I tried changing the backcolor to "transparent" because I thought of putting an imagebox under it and setting the link of the image there(say this one: https://media.tenor.com/images/cdcf2410001a5c02bcd371d13743aa57/tenor.gif)

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Which richtextbox? [winforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox)? [wpf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.richtextbox)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, you can add a `BlockUIContainer` to the document of your richtextbox. This allows you to input an `IElement` and display it as part of the document. This is great because that means you can input a picture here aswell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer?view=netframework-4.8

Sample:

```xml
    <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" BorderBrush="Gray">
        <FlowDocument>
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <!-- Here you can input any wpf controls, like the Image control. -->
                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="C:\Some\Image.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </BlockUIContainer>                
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Here's an stackoverflow answer that shows how to add an image from the web:

[Showing image in WPF using the URL link from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435829/showing-image-in-wpf-using-the-url-link-from-database)