# (WPF) Binding an Image to an URL via code does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, bitmap

After searching far and wide, and getting nowhere, I decided to ask.

I have a .NET 5.0 WPF project I am working on, and I have to bind an URL (of an online image) to the source of an image on my form.

I have tried the following:

```
CoverImage.Source = new BitmapImage("https://somesite..com/img.png");
```

as well as binding it via XAML:

```
///XAML:
<Image Name="CoverImage"
       Source="{Binding PreviewSource}"/>

///C#
public string PreviewSource { get; set; } = "https://somesite..com/img.png";
```

I have tried other solutions such as getting the image from a HrrpRequest and then creating it through a MemoryStream.

Using local images (that are on the pc) works without issues.

EDIT: mm8's solution started working for seemingly no reason (I have not touched the code at all since first testing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing image in WPF using the URL link from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435829/showing-image-in-wpf-using-the-url-link-from-database)

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please specify. If not, what is happening?

Comment: @CMGeek Unfortunately no, no errors. The images just don't load.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Just tried, no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://www.google.se/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"))`
```

and

```
<Image Name="CoverImage" Source="https://www.google.se/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"/>
```

...works just as expected on .NET 5.

Make sure that your URL is valid and reachable from your client machine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The XAML is working perfectly, however the first option still does not work. Is there anything else I have to setup for this to work?

Comment: No. Where and how are you setting creating the `BitmapImage`? Or why can't you go with the XAML solution?

Comment: Just started working today with your C# solution. I have not changed anything so I am unsure why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the datacontext is correct? It works for me in the app below.

**Xaml Code**

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="CoverImage" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private BitmapImage _imageSource;

    public BitmapImage ImageSource
    {
        get => _imageSource;
        set => SetProperty(ref _imageSource, value);
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://www.google.se/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"));
    }
}
```

**ViewModelBase**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(member, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        member = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
      
    }
```